# Deactivate or hide a project

Tags: azure-devops

Is It possible to deactivate or hide a project? I have many projects and I'd like to deactivate or hide the ones that I no longer use. I can't find an option to do that.

Comment: what not consider deleting project ? instead of deactive/hides ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. [You can not hide a project(this is still a feature that didn't achieve.)](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/hide-a-project-in-azuredevops/996079).

But you can set to let others can not viewable(Only allow people you allow to view this project.).